# How to debug the code in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, firebug

Is there is any other ways to debug the scripts,css,dom in IE.
We can do it with firebug in firefox.
Please provide the best option to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u tell me which versions of IE supports it except IE8.

Comment: @Odaiah IE9, it can be even installed on IE7, with IE6 i am not sure. I hate IE so much, but that Developer tool is actually better than Firebug for me...

Answer (score 2):

use IE developer toolbar for that, if you are using IE9 then press F12 to use the toolbar..
for older IE versions you can download from here:    http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

Answer (score 0):

yep, just hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

In IE we can use Developer Tool to debug css,html and js.
In most latest versions of IE it is included by default.For IE 8."Developer Tools" is integrated.you can press F12 to pop it up.or Click Tools from top then Developer Tools.